# How to match TemplateTypeParm node in Clang AST with AST_Matchers?

Tags: c++, c++11, clang, llvm, abstract-syntax-tree

I'm trying to get the RHS template type of a TypeAliasDecl.

Example:

```
using AliasOfType = AliasedType; // AliasedType itself is a template
```

I can retrieve `AliasOfType` in the AST using `clang::ast_matchers::typeAliasDecl`. I want to retrieve `AliasedType` with a `clang::ast_matchers::`.

The AST dump of `clang::ast_matchers::typeAliasDecl` looks like:

```
TypeAliasDecl 0x4fe22cf8 AliasOfType
  -SubstTemplateTypeParmType  0x4fe22cc0
   |-TemplateTypeParmType 0x4fe1a840 `AliasedType` dependent depth 0 index 0
   | `-TemplateTypeParm 0x4fe1a7f8 'AliasedType'
```

So intuitively, I'd want to match for `TemplateTypeParm` which has my previous match as an ancestor. However, I haven't found an `ast_matcher` that does that. There's `clang::ast_matchers::templateTypeParmType`, but it gives errors if I try to put anything as a narrowing parameter like:

```
templateTypeParmType(hasName("AliasedType"))
```

The error I get when I try that is:

```
clang/ASTMatchers/ASTMatchersInternal.h:1347:13: error: ‘clang::ast_matchers::internal::Matcher< <template-parameter-1-1> >::Matcher(const clang::ast_matchers::internal::DynTypedMatcher&) [with T = clang::TemplateTypeParmType]’ is private within this context
 return {Matcher<T>(std::get<Is>(Params))...};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right, there is no direct matcher that checks the aliased type of type alias (it is not that hard to implement it on your own, but I guess that should be the last resort).

However, there is a matcher `has` that according to the [documentation](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/LibASTMatchersReference.html):

> Matches AST nodes that have child AST nodes that match the
>   provided matcher.

Another important point is that type alias would definitely have a `TypeLoc` as a child. Here is a small quote on distinction between `Type`s and `TypeLoc`s (from [Internals Manual](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/InternalsManual.html#immutability)):

> we reuse Type nodes when representing the same type (but maintain separate TypeLocs for each instance where a type is written)

Putting it all together we get the following matcher:

```cpp
typeAliasDecl(has(typeLoc(loc(templateTypeParmType())).bind("x")))
```

For this code snippet:

```cpp
using NotInterestingAlias = int;

template <class AliasedType> class TemplateClass {
  using AliasOfType = AliasedType;
  using AliasOfSomeOtherType = double;
};

int main() { return 0; }
```

the matcher will produce the following output:

```
main.cpp:4:3: note: "root" binds here
  using AliasOfType = AliasedType;
  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
main.cpp:4:23: note: "x" binds here
  using AliasOfType = AliasedType;
                      ^~~~~~~~~~~
```

I hope this information is useful. Happy hacking with Clang!

Comment: Great! This works. I put the `has(typeLoc(loc(templateTypeParmType())).bind("x"))` in an `allOf` matcher that's enclosed in the `typeAliasDecl` matcher to get what I wanted.